# Relative orientation of satellite to a rotating plane.

Tags: matrices, geometry, orientation

**We know the GPS position of a Geostationry satellite and a sensor. We also know the sensor orientation relative to the magnetic North of Earth. *How do we find the orientation of Satellite relative to the current plane of sensor*?**

When the sensor is calibrated, its calibrated-xyz axes orients such that the xy-plane is parralell with the Earth surface, (y pointing North, x pointing East) and z pointing up ( z will go through center of Earth).

When sensor rotates, it will give out a quaternion, Q=(w, a,b,c) that descirbes its current orientatation (current-xyz) relatively to its calibrated-xyz.

To find out the relative orientation of sat on the current-xyz axes. We need to define a global coordinate, ABC.

I defined ABC such that AB is in the equatorial plane with A  passes through the 0° longitude, and B passes through +90° East, C passes through Earth North Pole.

I then convert the position of satellite and sensor into this ABC-coordinate.

The next step is to transform the ABC-coordinate to the current-xyz coordinate by mean of a single rotation ideally in quaternion form.

To do this, first I need the Q1 that describes rotation from current-xyz to calibrated-xyz. Q1 is the output of sensor.

Second, I need Q2 that describes  rotation from calibrated-xyz to global axes ABC.

- ***What is Q2 in this case ( possibly derive from its GPS coordinate and assumption that calibrated-xyz has xy tangential to sf of Earth)***?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be the position of sensor in global coordinates. Three orthogonal unit vectors giving the orientations of local axes can be then expressed in global coordinates as:
$$
\hat Z={(X,Y,Z)\over\sqrt{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}},\quad
\hat X={(-Y,X,0)\over\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}},\quad
\hat Y={(-XZ,-YZ,X^2+Y^2)\over\sqrt{(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)(X^2+Y^2)}}.
$$
The rotation matrix $R$ you need must then satisfy
$$
R(\hat X,\hat Y,\hat Z)=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1},
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
R=(\hat X,\hat Y,\hat Z)^{-1}=(\hat X,\hat Y,\hat Z)^{T}.
$$
In the above formula $(\hat X,\hat Y,\hat Z)$ is the matrix having $\hat X$, $\hat Y$, $\hat Z$ as column vectors, hence $R$ is the matrix having $\hat X$, $\hat Y$, $\hat Z$ as row vectors.

Comment: Hi Aretino, Thanks for your prompt response.
I understand how you get Z( align with gravity) and Y( cross product of Z and X) axes. But, How did you derive the  X axis?
Also, Since your proposed method involve the inversion of Matrix (X^,Y^,Z^), 
Do you know what is the best way to go about it?
This is because Matrix inversion could introduce an unacceptable margine of error.

Comment: Vector $\hat X$ is $(0,0,1)\times \hat Z$ normalized, so it is directed eastwards. As for the errors, sorry but I'm not an expert of numerical algorithms.

Comment: But on better thinking, you simply have $R^{-1}=R^T$ (the transpose), as with any orthogonal matrix. I also added that to the answer.

Comment: Now this makes sense. Thanks Aretino.